# Power management issues

Tags: power-management, lenovo, laptop, battery

I'm writing to you because I'm having problems with the battery on my computer.

Let me explain: when I plug in my computer, sometimes it recharges and the battery goes up... sometimes it stays at 0% and it recharges nothing.
Sometimes the computer indicates it's at 100%, so I unplug the charger and after a few minutes the computer shuts down without any warning.

Sometimes, I have to plug in the charger to turn on the computer even if the battery is full !

What can I do to get the battery to recharge normally?
Thanks for your help.

My computer is Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 7th with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu, It is a hardware problem: the battery is independent of the OS you use. I would assume the battery is broken and it is in need of a replacement.

Comment: For me it looks like an hardware issue. Try another OS and check you are facing this same issue or replace your battery with a new one. Consulting a technician is a better option IMO.

Comment: Hello Rinzwind et Ajay, thanks for your answers.